# What actions earn XP in The Guild 2?

Tags: guild-2

What actions earn XP in the Guild 2?  What action generates the most XP?

Answer (score 2):

pretty much doing anything gives you xp. beating a person up, robbing them, breaking their bones, and finishing them off gives quite some xp, but this has to be done without guards or bailiff seeing. getting into office gives you up to 600 xp, depending on the office seat you applied for.